# Border Corner in React Native for QR Code Scanner

Tags: react-native, user-interface, view, border, qr-code

How to implement the border corner only in react native for the qr code scanner.

This is my code:

```
<BarCodeScanner
            onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : handleBarCodeScanned}
            style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}
          />
        </View>
        <View
          style={[
            styles.frame,
            {
              width: qrCodeDimensions.width || 250,
              height: qrCodeDimensions.height || 250,
            },
          ]}
        />
      </View>
```

[image]

This is what I have tried. And I want to be like the other qr code scanner.

I want my outcome to be like this:
[image]

How to implement it? Please help me if you have an answer to my question. Thank you.